# Physical/Bridge and KVM ports shows up even after unplugged the cable!

Tags: debian, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge, bridged-adapter

We have Debian 10, it has two physical interfaces which we bridge to KVM.

The issue I have is, when I shutdown the port from my virtual operating system or I disconnect the cable the birdge and physical interface of the host image (Debian 10) still shows up. and in virtual machine its shows up as well . what is could be reason?
Below is my network config file.

```
# Backplane ("internal") network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.0.4
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0

# Front panel (RJ45) network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

auto br1
iface br1 inet static
        address 192.168.1.4
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        bridge_ports eth1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

ip link output

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br1 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:b8:c5:9a:63:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:b8:c5:9a:63:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:b8:c5:9a:63:59 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 94:b8:c5:9a:63:58 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br1 state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:24:91:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: vnet1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:09:c5:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Comment: Please show full `ip link` output on the host (put it [into the question](https://serverfault.com/posts/1121011/edit)).

Comment: Hello Nikita,  i have added the output and put it into my question, and also i have edited about my issue, just checked that in virtual machine its shows up as well even the cable disconnected